# Why are subnet masks specified in full dot notation, rather than just a number?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

Subnet masks for IPv4 (dunno about v6) are specified in full dot notation, e.g. `255.255.255.0`.  This means that the lower eight bits can be used to assign IP addresses to devices on a LAN (if I understand correctly).  Why write out the full subnet when I can just say `8`, i.e. the number of 0 bits in the mask (since they're all on the lower end)?

Comment: It depends on the context. some software was originally written before CIDR notation, and there are also circumstances where odd masks are useful, but many cases use the CIDR notation. IPv6 only uses CIDR notation, and really only `/64` for subnets (there are a few corner cases where you may use `/127` or `/128`).

Comment: It seems to me the premise of this question is invalid, since specifying a netmask as a number of bits is the standard way to do it with IPv6 and in the case of IPv4 it is supported in most places where a netmask is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's more meaningful to indicate the number of bits set in the mask, rather than the number of bits unset. That would be /24. That is, in turn, because masks are more often used to answer the question "Is the destination in the same network as I am ?", and the answer would depend on bitwise *AND* between the mask and IP address. If the result of such operation on the source IP and mask and the destination IP and same mask will be identical, this means that they are in the same network, so no gateway interaction is needed.

And yes, slash notation is more handy, but it's also more complex to understand, because it requires the understanding of mask/prefix purpose. Lots of people lack this  understanding, so it's easier for them to use the usual IP notation they are familiar with. That is the main reason of such notation.

Comment: When it comes to networking equipment like routers, most of the software was originally written before CIDR notation. The vendors haven't changed to CIDR notation where it existed before because it would break all the existing configurations. I have seen vendors new to the game, and vendors which add something new, using the CIDR notation. For instance, IPv6 is new and is only using CIDR notation. I have also seen some IPv4 stuff added to Cisco which uses CIDR notation, but Cisco can't change that interface addresses use dotted-decimal notation because it will break customer configurations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first sentence, I don't really see how it relates to the two options in the question. The two options presented are: specifying the exact mask in its entirety (eg 255.255.252.0) or saying that the mask is a prefix of length n with all bits set to 1 (eg /22).  Being able to specify a non-consecutive mask (eg 255.254.255.0, as described by Some Linux Nerd in another answer) is of course theoretically flexible but it's not very useful for most practical applications.

Comment: As for someone who does not understand the purpose of the netmask/prefix, I doubt that they would make sense of either and entering a single number that you don't understand instead of four dot-separated numbers that you don't understand wouldn't make much difference, if anything it would probably be easier to just enter the single number.

Comment: Non-continuous masks are sophistic. This is sort of mind joke or internet trolling. See my comment to that local genius.

Answer (score 1):

There are netmasks that can be defined in dotted notation that can't be defined in CIDR notation. You should avoid using non CIDR netmasks in real life. Example is:

```
    10.0.0.0 255.254.255.0
```

Note that there's a bit flipped in the second octet. This turns into two ranges of ip addresses that's defined in a single network + subnet. If I can find a pencil and paper I'll say what two ranges that equals.

Comment: 10.0.0.1-254 and 10.1.0.1-254 I think

Comment: Non-continuous masks are purely theoretical, even sophistic. They cannot be used, because they exclude some host in them. There's no mechanisms of routing and announcing such bogus prefixes, so only continuous masks are used, and if more discretion is needed, subnet is splitted to smaller subnets.

Comment: There's no good reason for it not to work, the netmask is mainly for separating the lan from the stuff that needs to go through the gateway.

Comment: I - implementation. You have nothing behind you except a theory. Prove it in a production envirnment.

Comment: Supported by openbsd, therefore non theoretical: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsUlySdtqaw

Comment: OpenBSD userbase and wildlife incidence is purely hypothetical. I'd say it's limited to the environments of the openbsd.org infrastructure itself.

Comment: Good point, I guess until someone actually uses OpenBSD for something it IS theoretical.